# Null parameters doing HTTP POST from Ajax to Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

I've read several StackOverflow posts about this and corrected my code several times
but I cant get my webAPI post method to work. I'm trying to receive a post parameter
but it comes always null.

What I am trying to do is receiving a base64 string that represents a canvas that is
creating with jquery when the user clicks the button:

```
function MakePhoto(ctrl) {

    html2canvas(ctrl, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL()
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "../api/webinfo",
                type: "POST",
                data: { imagedata: canvasData },
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

my `WebInfoController.cs` looks like this:

```
 public void Post([FromBody]string imagedata)
 { 
            
 }
```

imagedata parameter comes always **NULL**

And this are the headers I am receiving at webapi:

> "Method: POST,
>
> `RequestUri: 'http://myhost/RestFulApi/api/webinfo'`
>
> Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent
>
> User-Agent: Chrome/27.0.1453.94
>
> Content-Length: 42226
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8}

I hope you could help me.

Thanks

Comment: And what does canvas.toDataURL() return, are you sure it's not null? insert a console.log(canvasData) before your ajax-request, what's logged in the browser console?

Comment: I think you may need to add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax call.

Comment: I added dataType: "json" and It is still not working :(. @soderslatt yeah, I am debugging with chrome and it is not null. I can see the base64 string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the problem after some hours researching. I had to pass the data parameter to ajax function using:

`"=" + canvasdata, without the parameter name:`

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "../api/webinfo",
                type: "POST",
                data: "=" + canvasData,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```